# Javascript xml nightmare

Tags: javascript, xml

am learning javascript and not at a great rate, am trying to use the code to create a google map v3 api with searchable locations which load from an xml file.

Ran into a problem, many infact, but here is this one: I can not access the data in the xml file, i have used an example and tried to adjust it via reading and trying different code but to no success.

It is not accessing the data using my xml file, this is my xml format with the js code below:

```
    <markers style="MEDIUM">
       <marker>
         <title>McDonalds</title>
         <lat>55.5452</lat>
         <lng>34.3755</lng>
         <markerId>0</markerId>
         <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
         <address>Somewhere in London</address>
         <description>Get a free toy with every happy meal!</description>
       </marker>
    </markers>
```

This is the JS from my html file.

```
downloadUrl("london.xml", function(doc) {
            var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
            var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
             // obtain the attribues of each marker
              var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lat"));
              var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lng"));
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

              var description = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("description");
              var title = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("title");
          alert(title);
              // create the marker
              var marker = createMarker(point,title,description);
            }
        alert(i);
```

I imagine it is something very simple such as linking the nodes, but I can not figure it out and thought some help or advice would save me some sanity, thanks guys.

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: I get 1 alert reading: undefined

From what ive been playing around with i should be getting an alert with title value in my alert

Comment: Sorry for this, but could you append something for those alerts, maybe alert('1:'+title) and alert('2:'+i)

Comment: Are you able to use debugging tools? chrome and safari both have a great built in debugger. Internet Explorer 9 also has a built in debugger

Comment: Vision has just solved this, sorry. don't worry it will not be long until i get stuck again, i find this j/s alot harder than html :(

Comment: you might not get stuck as often if you used the debugging tools.

Comment: ive just started to use javascript console, keep using alert as a method of debugging what data is where, i dont know much about debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is hard to say definitely where all the problems are... However, the first problem I can see is that you are trying to `getElementsByTagName` from `documentElement` but you need to take it from `xmlDoc`:

```
var markers = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

Then, you are trying to convert `NodeList` object to `float`. It should be redone to:

```
var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].textContent);
var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lng")[0].textContent);
```

Next, I believe `description` and `title` are stored in the `textContent` of the first nodes with the corresponding names. So,

```
var description = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].textContent;
var title = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent;
```

And don't forget to check the right format of your XML file (including `<?xml ...?>` header, etc.)

Comment: thanks, but this is not solving the issue sadly, am still trying to fix this though

Comment: @Renai, please check the post update, consider taking markers from `xmlDoc`.

Comment: Yes, legend!!! Thanks so much man. How was this so simple for you ?
Am still very new to j/s + xml and have trouble understanding the way they work together although i keep fiddling but i dont always know what am doing. thanks again.

Comment: @Renai, well, some googling for `javascript parse xml example` may also help to resolve the problems with this topic :)

Comment: Things just get stranger, the list now loads my places next to a google map, but when i select a name, the markers are in the sea, LOL, oh shit what have i done now.

Comment: Dont worry its fixed now ;)
Never over look your own stupidity to set lat as lng and vice versa, that is what this javascript does. Puts brain in melt down. Well for a beginner anyway.

Comment: @Renai, congratulations! :) Funny, but swapping lng and lat was my first idea to advice you. However, I thought the problem was somewhere deeper.